# Capturing text with Python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I've been having a bit of trouble with capturing strings between html tags using Python regular expressions. I've been trying to capture the string "example link 2" from the string below:

```
<link>example link 1</link>
<item>
     <link>example link 2</link>
</item>
```

I've got this so far:

```
(?<=<link>)(.*)(?=</link>)
```

However the regular expression above returns "example link 1" and "example link 2". Could anyone please help with selecting only "example link 2"?

EDIT: Unfortunately I'm required to use regular expressions for this question so i can't use a parser etc. Thanks for the recommendation though.

Comment: Use a parser instead.

Comment: `'<link>(.*?)</link>'` might be better.  The `?` gives a minimal match.

Comment: use [elementtree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and xpath

Comment: Do not use regexes for HTML! HTML like xml supports tag nesting and Python `re` module does not like it at all...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'g' modifier at the end. For example the regex should look like:

```
/(?<=\<link>)(.*)(?=<\/link>)/g
```

The 'g' modifier tells the engine not to stop after the first match has been found, but rather to continue until no more matches can be found.
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/oF9eM7/2)